# Integral of Pointwise Multiplication of Mollifier and Function?

Tags: functional-analysis, convolution

Say I have a mollifier defined by
$$
\Phi\rho(x)=\int\rho(\tau)\mathbb{1}_{-1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon}(x-\tau) d\tau=\varphi(x)
$$
where 
$$
\rho(x)=\begin{cases} e^{-1/(1-\lvert x \rvert^{2})}/K & \text{ if } x \in (-1,1) \\
0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
where $K=\int_{-1}^{1} e^{-1/(1-\lvert x \rvert^{2})} \, dx$ and then for some function $f \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ I want to evaluate
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\varphi(x) \, dx
$$
So I'm (almost) sure that I can simplify this to be 
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\varphi(x) \, dx=\int_{-1}^{1} f(x)\varphi(x) \, dx
$$
but here I reach a problem. On one hand, this seems like it *should* be like multiplying by the indicator function of a set so we'd have
$$
\int_{-1}^{1} f(x)\varphi(x) \, dx=\int_{-1}^{1} f(x) \, dx
$$
since the mollifier and the indicator function are *a.e.* equal pointwise on $(-1,1)$ (or perhaps I'm mistaken here?). Basically my question is, how does one evaluate the integral of the pointwise product of a mollifier and some $f \in L^{1}$? I apologize if this question is too elementary but I'd appreciate any insight anyone can offer.

Comment: the support of $\varphi(x)$ is $[-1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon]$ so $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \varphi(x)dx = \int_{-1-\epsilon}^{1+\epsilon} f(x) \varphi(x)dx = \int_{-1}^1 f(x)dx+  \int_{[-1-\epsilon,1] \cup[1,1+\epsilon]}f(x) \varphi(x)dx$ where the last is $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon)$ but the $\mathcal{O}$ constant depends on $f$ (for example it is concentrated on $[1,1+\epsilon]$)

Comment: Ok so basically what you are saying is that if $f$ is a sufficiently pathological function, then it could "outpace" how fast $\varphi$ vanishes at the boundary $[-1-\epsilon,-1] \cup [1,1+\epsilon]$?

Comment: Sorry what I said is not correct, I meant $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon)$ if $f$ is bounded in the neighborhood of $x=1$, otherwise if $f$ is just $L^1$ then it is $o(1)$. Now it is not clear your question was about that, what do you want to do next ?

Comment: Ok so for my $f \in L^{1}$, then the $\int_{[-1-\epsilon,1]\cup[1,1+\epsilon]} f(x)\varphi(x) \, dx$ term goes to zero as epsilon goes to zero? It's been awhile since I used the little o notation so I might be wrong here.

Comment: Yes of course $|\varphi(x)| \le 1$ and $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_1^{1+\epsilon} f(x)\varphi_\epsilon(x)dx < \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_1^{1+\epsilon} |f(x)|dx = 0$ since $f \in L^1$